# Python string seperator

Tags: python, shapes

I am writing a program to join a string from a list and numbers together but I cant get rid of the quotations around the string. I need the semicolon after the string, the y coordinate and the radius but i dont need the commas after the semicolon. is this possible?
I expect the format to be as follows:

```
Circle; 80, 72; 15; 32, 208, 86
```

I've tried single semicolons and removing the comma and it did not work

```
from random import randrange
from random import choice


def randomShape():
    x = randrange (0,400)
    y = randrange (0,400)
    radius = randrange (0,100)
    red = randrange (192, 208)
    blue =randrange(100,140)
    green =randrange(150,175)
    shape = ['square;' , 'rectangle;']
    randomShape = choice (shape)
    JoinList =(randomShape,x,y,radius,red,blue,green)
    print(JoinList)

def main():

  randomShape()


main()
```

Comment: can you post what your desired output should look like?

Comment: Circle; 80, 72; 15; 32, 208, 86

Comment: `(randomShape,x,y,radius,red,blue,green)` isn't joining the any thing, it's creating a `tuple` comprised of the values. Where is `Circle` come from shown in your expected format?

Comment: I should be able to create random x,y,radius,red,blue, and green randomly

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to create a string but your output is a list.
You can achieve this result by simply using a string pattern with placeholders for your variables. You can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for this. I've put this code into a separate function to get rid of the mess:

```
def join_shape_data(shape, x, y, radius, red, blue, green):
    return f"{shape} {x}, {y}; {radius}; {red}, {blue}, {green}"
```

So you can call it inside your randomShape() function and this will generate what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just to **print** as in the mentioned format, then replace the print statement  like this:

```
print(randomShape,x,",",y,";",radius,";",red,",",blue,",",green)
```

**Output**:

```
rectangle; 219 , 300 ; 58 ; 207 , 114 , 172
```

This should solve.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variables:

```
In [83]: randomShape,x,y,radius,red,blue,green = 'Circle', 80, 72, 15, 32, 208, 86
```

Format a string with the classic % Python style:

```
In [84]: '%s; %d, %d; %d; %d, %d, %d'%(randomShape,x,y,radius,red,blue,green)                        
Out[84]: 'Circle; 80, 72; 15; 32, 208, 86'
```

and if we put that string a `print`:

```
In [85]: print(_)       
Circle; 80, 72; 15; 32, 208, 86
```

Or with the newer `format` style:

```
In [88]: '{}; {}, {}; {}; {}, {}, {}'.format(randomShape,x,y,radius,red,blue,green)                  
Out[88]: 'Circle; 80, 72; 15; 32, 208, 86'
```

The newer 'f' string variation has already been mentioned:

```
In [90]: f'{randomShape}; {x}, {y}; {radius}; {red}, {blue}, {green}'                                
Out[90]: 'Circle; 80, 72; 15; 32, 208, 86'
```